# Harry’s the most commercially successful

Tags: grammar

> But it’s not surprising to me that Harry’s **the most commercially successful** because he really fits the mold of a modern star.”

[Source](https://www.google.co.kr/amp/s/news.yahoo.com/amphtml/news/louis-tomlinson-admits-jealous-harry-163028768.html)

---

1. I'd like to know if "**the most commercially successful**" acts as a noun.
2. I'd like to know if "**the most commercially successful**" is short for "the most commercially successful one".

Comment: It's not "short for" the same clause with ***one*** attached. Consider *We're both smart, **but you're the smartest*** (and article-less ***...but you're smartest*** AND ***...but you're smarter***). Just because it's "syntactically valid" to extend the first of those with ***one*** doesn't mean my version is "short for" the relatively clunky utterance *We're both smart, but you're the smartest **one***.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that sentence, "the most commercially successful" is the *subject complement*. It's ambiguous whether it functions as an adjective or a noun.

Here's two versions of the same grammar structure that parse clearly with an adjective in that position:

> Harry is **successful**.
> Harry is **more successful** (than his sister).

The adjective in your sentence happens to be *superlative*, so it could just be a superlative adjective in the same position as the adjectives in these two examples.

At the same time, comparative and superlative phrases can be used as nouns:

> I only buy **the best**. (*object*)
> **The fastest** doesn't always win. (*subject*)
> I'm **the taller** of the two. (*subject complement*)

When acting as noun phrases, they are short forms of phrases that include the noun, such as "the best (things)" and "the fastest (racer)", "the taller (man)".

Answer (score 1):

Sample: But it’s not surprising to me that Harry’s **the most commercially successful** because he really fits the mold of a modern star.”

That phrase is adjectival.

Harry is the most commercially successful. It isn't an ellipsis.  Commercially is an adverb modifying the adjective *successful.* And the structure is a superlative (the most successful).

Harry is the most successful.
Mary is the most beautiful.

Those are adjectives.

Answer (score 1):

With additional context:

> Only ‘cos I didn’t know where to place myself, and really my only point of reference was other members of the band. But it’s not surprising to me that Harry’s **the most commercially successful** because he really fits the mold of a modern star.

The listener understands this to mean 'the most commercially successful *of the band members*'. In the terminology of [CGEL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Cambridge_Grammar_of_the_English_Language), this is called an **implicit partitive fused-head NP** (noun phrase). "Implicit" because the containing set (of the band members) is not directly provided, but can be understood from context. "Fused-head" because the NP is not centered around a noun or pronoun, but rather an adjective phrase ("most commercially successful"). Inserting "one" would make it a more typical NP.